# exception.ConstraintViolationException when execute POST request for a @ManyToOne Object

Tags: java, sql, spring, http, spring-data-jpa

I am new to JPA and Spring and I am encountering a problem when trying to send a Post request to create a review object. I am not sure if my ManytoOne object creation cause the problem. I use postgresql for database.

This is the error code:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2022-06-15T15:55:27.103+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [title\" of relation \"review]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
  "path": "/api/v1/movie/review/Egg"
}
```

Here is my request method and service method:

```
 @PostMapping  (path = "/review/{movieTitle}")
    public void addNewReview(@PathVariable String movieTitle, @RequestBody Boolean like){

        movieService.addNewReview(movieTitle, like);
    }
```

```
 public void addNewReview(String title, boolean like) {
        Movie m = getMovieByTitle(title);
        Review review = new Review(m, like);
        reviewRepository.save(review);
    }
```

Review table has a many to one relationship to the movie table. The review class is below:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private int likes;
    private int dislikes;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "title", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Movie movie;

    public Review(Movie movie, boolean like) {
        this.movie = movie;
        if(like){
            this.likes = 1;
            this.dislikes = 0;
        }else{
            this.likes = 0;
            this.dislikes = 1;
        }
    }
```

Movie class is below:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Movie {
    @Id
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Integer releaseYear;
    private double duration;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Review> reviews;

    @Transient
    private double rating;

    public Movie(String title, String description, Integer releaseYear, double duration) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
```

Thank you for your help! I am stuck here for a day and cannot figure out why title violates the constraint(which is foreign key constraint)

Comment: If you can add the stack trace, it would be helpful in determining what's happening.

Comment: The spring application compiles and runs without problem. It is just that I cannot insert entries into the review table. The only error i get is when send a POST request

Comment: yes but there was an error which is why you received that response, the 500 indicates that an unhandled exception occurred.  Include that stack trace.